# Access to a private variable in a C++ class that contains an array of structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct, private, encapsulation

I am writing a C++ class that will contain an array of structures.

```
typedef struct
{
  int         a;
  int         b;
  std:string  c;
} MyElementType;


class MyClass
{
  private:
    MyElementType   myElement1;
    std::vector <MyElementType>     myElementVector1;

  public:
    MyElementType   myElement2;
    std::vector <MyElementType>     myElementVector2;

    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    void addMyElement1 (int, int, std::string);

    // Other methods.

};
```

I need to insert objects of type MyElementType into the vector From main.

I can insert elements into the vector myElementVector2 like this:

```
int main ()
{
  MyClass myClassObj;

  myClassObj.myElement2.a = 2;
  myClassObj.myElement2.b = 20;
  myClassObj.myElement2.c = "text2";

  myClassObj. myElementVector2.push_back(myClassObj.myElement2);


}
```

To do the same with myElementVector1 I must call the public method defined in the MyClass class:

```
  myClassObj.addMyElement1 (1, 10, "text1");
```

Having defined the addMyElement1 method like so:

```
void MyClass::addMyElement1 (int la, int lb, std::string lc)
{
  MyElementType   lmyElement1;

  lmyElement1.a = la;
  lmyElement1.b = lb;
  lmyElement1.c = lc;

  myElementVector1.push_back(lmyElement1);
};
```

This example is very simple, but in the real program the MyElementType structure has more than twenty fields and some of them are a vector instead of a simple data type. Something similar to this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int         ID;
  std:string  NAME;
} MyElementType2;

typedef struct
{
  int         a;
  int         b;
  std:string  c;
  vector <MyElementType2> v;
} MyElementType;
```

To insert objects into myElementVector2 you would need a public function that receives all these parameters, creates myElement1 and inserts it into myElementVector1

It could be something like this, but I don't know how to pass the parameter with the vector v (which will contain several objects of type MyElementType2) and have all that added to myElementVector1

```
void MyClass::addMyElement1 (int la, int lb, std::string lc, ¿ VECTOR_PARAM ?)
{
  MyElementType   myElement1;

  myElement1.a = la;
  myElement1.b = lb;
  myElement1.c = lc;
  ¿ myElement1.v = VECTOR_PARAM; ?

  myElementVector1.push_back(myElement1);
};
```

Any suggestions or help are appreciated as I haven't found any information on this.

Comment: `const std::vector<MyElementType2>& v`?

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using, which teaches "typedef struct" for C++ code? That looks like a pretty bad textbook. This construct is legacy C and is never needed in proper C++ code.

Comment: To use the solution that Alan proposes, in main I must create the object v and then pass it by reference to addMyElement1, but instead what I try is to pass from main only the values that will be stored in the vector v and in MyElementType, in a way that the details of the code are hidden in the class.
Could that be possible?